# Как составить правильно запрос?

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. Есть таблица с title значений вот такие.

-00.50, -00.75, -01.00,-01.25, -01.50, -01.75, -02.00, -02.25, -02.50, -02.75, -03.00, -03.25, -03.50, -03.75, -04.00, -04.25, -04.50, -04.75, -05.00, -05.25, -05.50, -05.75, -06.00, -06.00, -06.50, -07.00, -07.50, -08.00, -08.50, -09.00
+00.50, +00.75, +01.00,+01.25, +01.50, +01.75, +02.00, +02.25, +02.50, +02.75, +03.00, +03.25, +03.50, +03.75, +04.00, +04.25, +04.50, +04.75, +05.00, +05.25, +05.50, +05.75, +06.00, от +06.00, +06.50, +07.00, +07.50, +08.00

Значение вбиты в разнобой. Так вот как сделать запрос что бы сортировал значения вот так вот.

от +08.00 до +00.50 от -0.50 до -9.00

делаю order_by asc выводит вот так от +0.50 до +9.00 дальще -0,5 до -9,0

Как сделать правильно запрос!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

`SELECT my_value FROM my_table ORDER BY (my_value+0) DESC`

```
my_value
8.00
7.50
7.00
6.50
6.00
6.00
5.75
5.50
5.25
5.00
4.75
4.50
4.25
4.00
3.75
3.50
3.25
3.00
2.75
2.50
2.25
2.00
1.75
1.50
1.25
1.00
0.75
0.50
-0.50
-0.75
-1.00
-1.25
-1.50
-1.75
-2.00
-2.25
-2.50
-2.75
-3.00
-3.25
-3.50
-3.75
-4.00
-4.25
-4.50
-4.75
-5.00
-5.25
-5.50
-5.75
-6.00
-6.00
-6.50
-7.00
-7.50
-8.00
-8.50
-9.00
```

Comment: Спасибо работает. Оказывается можно так)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, просто два SELECTа а потом объединить:

```
(SELECT value FROM title WHERE value > 0.5 AND value < 9.00 ORDER BY title ASC)
UNION ALL
(SELECT value FROM title WHERE value < -0.5 AND value >-9.0 ORDER BY title DESC)
```